# Difference between Function pointer and passing pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

## I have these codes...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int * Function (int  a, int  b);


int main() 
{
int a = 2;
int b = 7;
int * x = &a;
int * y = &b;

cout << a << "   " << *x << endl;
cout << b << "   " << *y << endl;

Function (a , b);
cout << endl << endl; 
cout << a << "   " << *x << endl;
cout << b << "   " << *y << endl;

cout << endl << endl; 
cout << a << "   " << *x << endl;
cout << b << "   " << *y << endl;

Function (a ,  b);
cout << endl << endl; 
cout << a << "   " << *x << endl;
cout << b << "   " << *y << endl;

cout << endl << endl; 
cout << a << "   " << *x << endl;
cout << b << "   " << *y << endl;

system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

int * Function (int  a, int  b)
{
    int pom; 
     pom =  a;
     a = b; 
     b = pom;

}
```

#### This one is Function pointer and  do not change variables. I dont know why, and what exactly means Fucntion pointer. Why is this kind of pointers useful ?

### Versus

```
  #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;


 int  Function (int * a, int * b);


int main() 
{
int a = 2;
int b = 7;
int * x = &a;
int * y = &b;

cout << a << "   " << *x << endl;
cout << b << "   " << *y << endl;

Function (&a , &b);
cout << endl << endl; 
cout << a << "   " << *x << endl;
cout << b << "   " << *y << endl;

cout << endl << endl; 
cout << a << "   " << *x << endl;
cout << b << "   " << *y << endl;

Function (&a , & b);
cout << endl << endl; 
cout << a << "   " << *x << endl;
cout << b << "   " << *y << endl;

cout << endl << endl; 
cout << a << "   " << *x << endl;
cout << b << "   " << *y << endl;

system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

int  Function (int * a, int * b)
{
    int pom; 
     pom =  *a;
     *a = *b; 
     *b = pom;        
}
```

#### This is ordinary passing by pointers, this change a variables like books learn. I am interested how to use passing by pointer for expamle arrays.

Comment: There is no function pointer, there is a function which returns a pointer (and misses a `return` statement).

Comment: You are looking at 2 different things. Your first version of the function returns a pointer to an int and takes 2 ints as arguments. Your second version of the function returns an int and takes 2 pointers to ints as arguments. Neither of these versions is a function pointer.

Comment: I *THINK* you are trying to ask "what are pointers good for", but perhaps there is a language barrier. The answer to that is found here :
 http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyCPointers.html

Answer (score 1):

you are mixing the concepts, none of those a funtion pointers

```
int * Function (int  a, int  b);
int  Function (int * a, int * b);
```

this:

```
int * Function (int  a, int  b);
```

is a function that takes by value 2 ints and returns a pointer to an int

and this

```
int  Function (int * a, int * b);
```

is a function that takes 2 pointers to ints and returns an int